# String new Object and comparision

Tags: java, string, operators

As of i know any changes on String a new Object will create,and for some run time activity if there is a content change then a new object will create in Heap are, but i am confusing on below cases, please give idea...

```
String s8="abcd";
String s9=s8.toUpperCase();
String s11=s8.toUpperCase();
System.out.println("S9 "+s9.hashCode() +"  s10 "+s11.hashCode());//S9 -- 2001986  s10 -- 2001986
System.out.println(s9==s11);//false
```

In the above scenario the address is printing same but the == operator shaowing false.

please tell why address is same and comparision is false.

Comment: `s9.hashCode()` is not an address. `String` class overrides `hashCode`. The value depends on the contents of the `String`.

Comment: Sorry please more elaborate why s9==s11 is false

Comment: @Goutam Each call to `.toUpperCase()` returns a new String.

Comment: But the content will same means the same object will reuse right
but when calling 
String s11=s9.toUpperCase() then the result is true...
  String s6=new String("goutamgiri");
  String s7=s6.toString();
  System.out.println(s6==s7);// true because the content is same and the same object will resue..... because of this only i am confusing

Comment: Use of `==` with objects compares identity (is it the exact same object), you need to use `.equals()` to check if they are equal (same value, but possibly different object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s8="abcd"; : Memory will be allocated from constant pool.

String s9=s8.toUpperCase(); New object will be created on heap

String s11=s8.toUpperCase(); Another  New object will be created on heap
```

If you look at the implementation of `toUpperCase`

```
public String toUpperCase(Locale locale) {

..

return new String(result, 0, len + resultOffset);
```

Hence it creates a new object on heap each time. therefore `s9 != s11`

> Note: If two objects are equal then their hashcodes are equal but vice
>   versa is not true

**UPDATE:**

```
String s11=s9.toUpperCase();
s11==s9 // returns true
```

Because there are not chars which can be modified and therefore s11 and s9 both points to the same object. I strongly recommend to you to read the implementation

Comment: String s11=s9.toUpperCase()//is it will create a new object in Heap? then
s9==s11//true why?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

`==` operator is used for reference comperison. Basically when you create `s9` and `s11` then only 1 object is created in heap. That's why those 2 hashcode is same and 2 different references are pointing same object. That's why `s9==s11` has retured false.